# Getting the value from a Map with zero or 1 entries?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

I have a Map instance and it will either have zero or 1 entries in it.  This is a demo:

```
class Todo {
   constructor(
   public id:string,
   public title:string,
   public description: string ) {}
}
const todo1 = new Todo('1', 't1', 'Sarah OConnor');
const m:Map<string, Todo> = new Map();
m.set('1', todo1);
const todoInMap= m.entries().next().value[1];
console.log("The todo in the map is: ", todoInMap);
```

This will log the `todoInMap` instance when it's in the Map, but if we `m.clear()` we will get an error.

This function can be used to avoid errors, I'm just wondering if Map API has a more simple way of doing this?

```
function getMapValue<E>(m:Map<any, E>) {
  if (!m.entries().next().done) {
    return m.entries().next().value;
  }
  return null;
}
```

[Ended up putting adding a utility method to Slice Utilities](https://github.com/fireflysemantics/slice/blob/master/src/utilities.ts#L132)

````
/**
 * Gets the current active value from the `active`
 * Map.  
 * 
 * This is used for the scenario where we are manging
 * a single active instance.  For example 
 * when selecting a book from a collection of books.  
 * 
 * The selected `Book` instance becomes the active value.
 * 
 * @example
 * const book:Book = getActiveValue(bookStore.active);
 * @param m 
 */
export function getActiveValue<E>(m:Map<any, E>) {
  if (m.size) {
    return m.entries().next().value[1];
  }
  return null;
}```
````

Comment: Javascript doesn't have a 'map' API. In javascript, to store maps all you have to do is have an 'object'. Then the object can have a string or number key with a value of any type.

Comment: Here's a demo of Map https://stackblitz.com/edit/slice-reactive-collection?file=index.ts

Comment: @programmerRaj, JavaScript has Map ;) https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map

Comment: @Ole, what error do you see. I don't see any errors in your demo

Comment: @Valerii I didn't know that. In that case, I don't know the answer to your question because I didn't even know that javascript maps existed!

Comment: @Valerii I'm just wondering whether there's a simpler cleaner / Sugar way of performing the check using the Map API.

Comment: I updated the question with a sample function that will perform the check and return the value or null.

Comment: If you need an ordered collection and not a keyed one, you might be better off using arrays, not Maps.

Comment: @georg as usual you have excellent points.  I'm storing multiple active entities in a Map for the @fireflysemantics/slice state manager, but I should probably just convert the values to an array have provide an API around managing the entries in that array for the purpose of observing active entities.

Comment: This is the state manager: https://www.npmjs.com/package/@fireflysemantics/slice

Comment: https://github.com/fireflysemantics/slice/blob/master/src/utilities.ts#L132

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this option would be better:

```
function getMapValue<E>(m:Map<any, E>) {
  if (m.size) {
    return m.entries().next().value;
  }
  return null;
}
```

It's very weird to have size as a property, not length or size() but it how it is :)